# Уменьшить расстояние между элементами списка li

Tags: html, css

Господа нужна помощь как уменьшить расстояние между элементами списка. Пробовал margin и padding ничего не помогает только мой код полностью отодвигается в сторону которую я впишу.
![Текст] (https://sun6-13.userapi.com/z70ALOrTiv5_uqPf2EbgzVEZWxBwJawkaflGGw/PAmTplN6dOs.jpg)

```css
footer {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: #F7680B;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
footer li {
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
.ftr {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: Fantasy;
}

#spn {
    margin-top: 1px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<ul>
                   <li><a class="ftr" href="#">Privacy</a> </li>
                   <li><a class="ftr" href="#">Terms</a> </li>
                   <li><a class="ftr" href="#">Contact</a> </li>
</ul>
                      <span id="spn"> &copy; Oculus, 2015 Copyright</span> 
</footer>
```

Comment: Добавил, там как я писал нужно только уменьшить расстояние между элементами списка.

Comment: Вы же сами задали `padding-right` в `70px`, уменьшите его..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавите вот это правило `footer li:not(:first-of-type){}` и меняйте расстояние так, как вам нужно. я поставил `-55px`.

```css
footer {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: #F7680B;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
footer li {
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

footer li:not(:first-of-type) {
 margin-left: -55px;
}
.ftr {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: Fantasy;
}

#spn {
    margin-top: 1px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<ul>
                   <li><a class="ftr" href="#">Privacy</a> </li>
                   <li><a class="ftr" href="#">Terms</a> </li>
                   <li><a class="ftr" href="#">Contact</a> </li>
</ul>
                      <span id="spn"> &copy; Oculus, 2015 Copyright</span> 
</footer>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло, я просто начинающий и не знал что есть такая функция :not(:first-of-type) теперь буду знать еще раз спасибо огромное поставил вам плюс за помощь)

Comment: @Eryk Tibijczyk, всегда рад помочь :)) p.s. если пропишите вот так - `footer li:first-of-type{}`, без `:not` , то затроните только первый элемент в списке, но не все остальные. Успехов вам в начинаниях!